# Activate AuthenticationGuard only if there's no query string

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular7, adal

I built an Angular 7.0.4 single page app which will be accessed by two different type of users. One type will have their identity set on Azure AD and the other won't.

So, my application when launched for the first set of users will authenticate them using ADAL. For the second set of users (who do not have an AD identity), there will be a windows application which will fetch their login information and then launch the website by passing their Id as a query string parameter.

So, for the first set of users my website URL will look like

```
https://my.application.com/
```

whereas for the second set of users it will be

```
https://my.application.com/?Id=12345
```

I'm trying to configure my routes in such a way that the authentication happens only when there's no query string parameter.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks,
Shreeram

I have set up ADAL for my app and tried configuring the routes this way

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from 'microsoft-adal-angular6';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
  { path: '?Id', component: DashboardComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

But even when I pass the query string parameter, it still authenticates the request.

Comment: Have you considered adding a child module that has this authguard?
This may help in keeping your code clean, unless your intention is to have this address dedicated to authentication only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requests with query string parameters are still hitting the AuthenticationGuard because your routing is set so. The RouterModule doesn't care if there are query params or not and will always be routing to the empty path in your example.

So, in order to prevent the AuthenticationGuard blocking your requests with the 'Id', you will need to change your routing to this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from 'microsoft-adal-angular6';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
  // { path: '?Id', component: DashboardComponent} <=== remove this line
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and then you can put an if-else statement inside your AuthenticationGuard like this:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from "./authentication.service";
import { CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router, CanLoad, Route } from "@angular/router";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
                            private route: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (state.url.indexOf('Id') > -1 { // Id exists
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // rest of your logic here
        }
    }


}
```

Hope it helps.